# Reloading items from firebase every change in route

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore

I wrote a service in angular that fetches items from firebase using snapshotChanges and return them. than in my component i subscribe to the data and store theme in an array. than i show the data in cards using ngFor.

Everytime i switch pages (without reloading) the data is being reloaded in a visible way, it hurts the UX and doesn't look good. i tried using take(1) but it didn't work. Sometimes it shows the same data multiple times.

Why is this happening and what should i do to fix it ?

Tank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to load the data in a wrapper component and pass it to the children. This happens because a component (and all of the loaded data) is destroyed when the component is left and the route is changed.

Comment: I think i solved it. I used ngOnDestroy to unsubscribe the fetching of the data and now i deleted it so i am still subscribing even though i change routes. is it a good way to solve the problem ?

Comment: Unless you need the data in a different component yes.